# Can big late hop addition hurt AIPA?

Tags: hops, ipa

I made two mistakes at the beginning of the boil, and I under-bittered my beer by 20 IBU. This is AIPA, so underbittering is serious mistake. Sadly, i only realized that by putting my notes back into Brewtarget at 15 minutes til the end of boil. I recovered using 35g Citra and 35g Mosaic at 10'. 26 liters ≈ 6.8 gallons batch. It got me bitterness I wanted (70 IBU in theory, and wort tastes just right). But my 20' addition was already there. I also still added 30g of Cascade at 0', for aroma. Didn't quite have a time to think it thorough, so, well... And I still plan to dry hop.

Is there something like "too hoppy" Black AIPA? And if it is, have I crossed the line already, or can I still hope for it to be "in style"?

Comment: Assuming this was a 5 gallon (or smaller) batch? I don't think a late (and large) hop addition would hurt anything, other than providing you more flavor and aroma.... and you said yourself, "wort tastes just right". At the end of the day, if you're happy with it, what else is there to say?

Comment: @brendo234 "beer judges"?

Answer (score 1):

You can correct IBU with a larger later addition.

I recently shifted one of my IPAs to a single large addition at 30 min, with great success. Giving it the desired IBU and more hop profile.

As far as judging.There is a Black IPA sub category now in 2015 bjcp guidelines. Sounds like this beer is on point for it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the thought on this board about re-boiling.  I have entered into a few "wort" competitions at local breweries where they provide a specified wort like pale or wheat and we, the homebrewers, do something with it and enter our finished product into a competition.  I have actually done well with a Mango Wheat.

Some guys re-boil the wort they pick up from the brewery.  This allows them to add addtional hops or even add new mash malt sugars and their beer turns out just as if they had created the wort themselves.  One guy who reboiled a wheat last year actually won his category and best of show.

So, if these guys are re-boiling this wort, what is the thought about Molot or anyone else re-boiling their wort in order to introduce missed hops or for any other reason.  I'd say, Molot, re-boil and add your hops to get your desired IBU rather than making due.

Comment: Reboiling is not quite an answer, as my boil didn't even finish at the moment I realized I made mistake. It was rolling all right.Also, as it would get rid of any aroma and flavor of my 20' addition, I wouldn't really save anything on hops, I'm afraid. Not enough to excuse another hour of boil if just large late addition might be acceptable.